# How can I delete an individual photo from my photostream?

Tags: macos, photos.app, photo-stream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you erase pictures from the Photo Stream album on an iPhone running iOS 5?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27398/how-do-you-erase-pictures-from-the-photo-stream-album-on-an-iphone-running-ios-5)

Either on my Mac, or on iPhone or iPad, how can I delete an individual image from my photostream? I can't seem to work this out...

Comment: @Daniel - you are right - I didn't find those questions when I looked. I will vote to close as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you can't. My guess is it will be included in the next iOS update though.