# iPhone 6 Photo stream deleting

Tags: photo-stream

When I delete photos from my iPhone on My Photo Stream, will the same photos also be deleted on other devices connected to the same Apple ID automatically?

Answer (score 2):

It depends - if the photo is out of the Photo Stream Window and your deletion included the message that "this photo will be deleted from all devices" then yes - one delete wipes it forever.

If not, you may need to clean things up using iCloud.com and/or wiping your entire photo stream once you have the photos you wish to keep stored outside photo stream.

You can review the basics on cleaning up Photo Stream here:

- [How do you erase pictures from the Photo Stream album on an iPhone running iOS 5?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27398/)

Things have changed since then and you have more options:

If you have sensitive photos, you can add them all to a hidden album. That places them in a "no thumbnail" / no preview state. If that's not enough, look over your current Deleted Items online directly from the cloud using https://www.icloud.com/#photos

That way, you know you are working with the authoritative version of all photos stored in iCloud.

1. Delete anything you don't need from deleted items to make sure your account is working and make it easy to permanently delete the offending images you want really purged.
2. Delete the images you want - follow up with purging them from Deleted Items.
3. Check your devices to make sure they followed the cloud deletion and don't have any stragglers.

Pay attention to the message that arrives when you delete an item. If it says it will be deleted on all devices, you know that device is in sync. If not, you will have to patrol all devices. This is easier by going to Settings - https://www.icloud.com/#settings - and making a check list of all the devices that could have your Photos from the stream.

Comment: thanks my friend for the answer but honestly I don't get it clearly, the situation is that I have shot some sensitive photos from my iPhone and I late I have deleted it from my photos streams. My concern is I have other devices with family member connected to same Apple ID , what is the best way to make sure that all photos I have already deleted are is removed also from that other device please . Please it's very important .

Comment: @Vella If you need guided help, Apple support is your best bet. Call them and explain you don't know how to use iCloud.com to verify that photos are deleted. They can walk you through how to tell which devices are associate with your account. This site is best for questions where you've already exhausted the troubleshooting and support and have a specific question on one well-documented issue. I can see you might need some explanation of how iCloud works so you're comfortable that you've controlled the pictures in question.

Comment: Bmike thanks for your reply, the problem I didn't find online support in my country. It seems you an idea how to solve my problem. I just need little more clearly about the last option of patrol all devices that you have mentioned on your answer . If this option can delete my photo that already been delivered to other devices I would be so glad and thankful. Please the situation is embarrassing and I need to ride out of it as soon as possible. Please mike help me because Iam so nervous about it. Thanks

Comment: @Vella I can't really improve on my answer unless you can clearly explain  (perhaps in a second question) what specific part of using iCloud.com you don't get. I understand your urgency but can't really offer more at this point. Perhaps someone else will see your plea and have more advice for you.

Comment: Mike, I have repeated my question which could help you to understand more my concern. When I go to setting in https://www.icloud.com/#settings and make check list of other devices might have my photos from my stream and then delete it. This will remove all photos that I deleted from that device ?

Answer (score 1):

First, for your picture to arrive at other Apple devices you'll have to have either

1. iCloud Photo Library on or
2. My Photo Stream on with automatic upload on the device that took the picture or
3. A shared album and iCloud Photo Sharing on

On the first case, deleting a picture from your Camera Roll will [delete it from any device with the same Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204570).

In the second scenario deleting a picture will pop up a message that warns you that

> The photo will also be deleted from Photo Stream on all your  devices

[image: delete photo stream warning]

If you delete it, it will remove it from Photo Stream an all connected devices.

But it **won't** remove it from the Camera Roll on iOS if someone already made a copy there, nor it will remove it from the library on [iPhoto](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2712) if you have "Automatic Import" switched on or [Photos app on OS X](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201317) with "Copy items to the Photos library" on. Same on Windows with iCloud.

The only way I can think it won't import to computers set up as described is that they were turned off or offline when the picture was deleted from Photo Stream, so there wasn't time for them to download and copy to the main library. I'm not sure if you need iPhoto or Photos open on OS X for the importing to happen.

On the third case, removing a photo from a shared album will remove it from all associated devices, if you are the owner of the album.

As suggested by @bmike, you should go check if the picture is available at icloud.com.
It should look something like this:
[image: icloud.com home]

You have to enter this address in a computer, as an Apple iOS device won't let you enter.

Click on the "Photos" icon and see what you can find there. Removing photos from there should remove it from associated devices, if they are setup as described before.

Comment: Thanks so much Jaime, I had the second scenario which is the photo streams was on when I took and then deleted those photos. But when I had deleted it manually from both camera roll and photo stream, the warning message that it would be deleted on all other devices didn't appears to me on that time. Does it mean that my photos didn't arrived to the other device at all? Thanks for your help

Comment: I would say that probably no other device has Photo Stream on. Anyway follow @bmike advice and check if the picture is on iCloud https://www.icloud.com/#photos, and try taking another picture to see if it appears there, and deleting it on your iPhone to see and what message appears and if it goes away in iCloud.

Comment: thanks so much for this information , I tried to follow Bmike advice to check if that photos on iCloud https://www.icloud.com/#photos, however, when I went there I couldn't find where to see those photos!

Comment: I'll add a screenshot later

Comment: Thanks so much Jaime for your willing to help me. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Added a screenshot, hope it helps. From what you've said, it appears there wasn't other devices configured with photo stream.

Comment: Good to hear that. In general, it's a good idea that each user has it's unique Apple ID. If you'd like to pay for your family purchases, you can setup Family Sharing.